# export linux OS users account to web app?

Tags: database, linux, web-applications

I have had a `Linux` machine on which there are many users.

Now I have to write a simple webapp(allow users submit a simple form).

Is it possible to use those OS user/password pairs instead of implement a registration system?

Do I have to dump `/etc/shadow` or something into database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and you don't have to dump the files to a database. You can read files from a web application.

Find a library for parsing the files. The specifics will depend on which language you are using but, for instance, Perl has [Password::Unix](https://metacpan.org/module/Passwd%3a%3aUnix).

Comment: But dose it mean that I have to run my web server as `root` to read `/etc/shadow`? Is it dangerouse?

Comment: No. The script should be suided so it runs as a user in the shadow group (which should have readonly access to /etc/shadow).